# Fields of request parameter object is null for PUT method in my SpringBoot REST server

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I'm writing a REST server in SpringBoot. I have implemented POST,GET,DELETE,PUT methods. CORS is enabled in my WebSecurity config:

```
http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
```

I have allowed HTTP methods:

```
  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    var corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfiguration.applyPermitDefaultValues();
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
    return source;
  }
```

I test the API using SwaggerUI and Postman. All methods work in SwaggerUI.  All the methods except PUT works in Postman but PUT does not work in Postman. When I debug for PUT request, I see that in my controller the fields in the parameter objects is null:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/reports/update", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
  public ResponseMessage updateReport(ReportPreference reportPreference) {
  //...
  }
```

Is there something I miss for PUT method?

Thanks

Comment: Where's the rest of your controller?

Comment: try `@RequestBody` in your method. Hard to say what is wrong without the full code

Comment: pvpkiran yes, using @RequestBody solved the issue but actually I can't understand what is the difference...